# Atomically undo-able function in Google Apps Script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, atomic, undo

I've made a function in *Google Apps Script* for use in *Google Spreadsheets*.  The function transforms a range in steps.

If the user tries to `undo`, it only undoes one of the steps of the function.

I'd like it to behave **atomically**, so using `undo` undoes the **whole thing**.  Is there a way to do this?

For context, a code snippet:

```
function onOpen() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var menuItems = [{name: 'Run myFunction', functionName: 'myFunction'}];
  spreadsheet.addMenu('Stuff', menuItems);
}

function myFunction(range) {
  range = range || SpreadsheetApp.getActiveRange();

  forRowInRange(range, replaceValues) ; // <= This should behave atomically!
}

function forRowInRange(range, fn) {
  // ...split range into sub-ranges for each row...
  // ...invoke fn on each sub-range...
}

function replaceValues(range) {
  // ...replace 1s with Xs, and 0s with spaces
}
```

Existing and desired behaviour

```
    |0|1|0|
  - |1|0|1| Initial state
/   |0|1|0|
|
|       |
|       V
|
|     | |X| |
|     |X| |X| After function is invoked
|     | |X| |
|
|        |
|        V
|
|     | |X| |
|     |X| |X| After undo is pressed once
|     |0|1|0|
|
|        |
|        V
|
|     | |X| |
|     |1|0|1| After undo is pressed twice
|     |0|1|0|
|
|       |
|       V
|
\   |0|1|0|
 -> |1|0|1| After undo is pressed three times (or ideally, ONCE)
    |0|1|0|
```

I'd like for undo to return to the initial state after **one** click, instead of *three*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

its not possible to control the undo behaviour. Google sheets has had that issue from the start and still doesnt work well.

you would need to write your own undo command, and it cant be hooked to the undo event.

Comment: Well, that's unfortunate. Oh well, thanks for the answer!